# Check multiple whois requests in a textarea

Tags: php, textarea, whois

I would like to create a whois function that can check availability for multiple domains (many different words at the same time).

I have this script which works for one single word. How can I get it to check multiple words (one word on each row in the textarea)?

For example if I type in to following in the textarea:

goodword

averygoodword

thisisagreatword

Here is the code:

```
<?php function checkDomain($domain,$server,$findText){
  // Open a socket connection to the whois server
  $con = fsockopen($server, 43);
  if (!$con) return false;

  // Send the requested doman name
  fputs($con, $domain."\r\n");

  // Read and store the server response
  $response = ' :';
  while(!feof($con)) {
  $response .= fgets($con,128);
  }

  // Close the connection
  fclose($con);

  // Check the response stream whether the domain is available
  if (strpos($response, $findText)){
  return true;
  }
  else {
  return false;
  }
  }

  function showDomainResult($domain,$server,$findText){
  if (checkDomain($domain,$server,$findText)){
  echo "<div id='left'>$domain</div><div id='next'>AVAILEBLE</div><div id='nycontainer'></div>";
  }
  else echo "<div id='left'>$domain</div><div id='next'>TAKEN</div><div id='nycontainer'></div>";
  }
  ?>

  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
  <html>
  <head>
  <title><?php $sidtitel ?></title>
  <link href="exempel1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body>

  <div id="titel"> <h1>Search domain</h1></div>
  <div id="main">
  <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" name="domain" id="domain">
  <textarea name="domainname"></textarea>

  <input type="checkbox" name="all" checked />All
  <input type="checkbox" name="se"/>.se
  <input type="checkbox" name="nu"/>.nu
  <input type="checkbox" name="eu"/>.eu
  <input type="checkbox" name="biz"/>.biz

  <input type="checkbox" name="com"/>.com
  <input type="checkbox" name="net"/>.net
  <input type="checkbox" name="org"/>.org
  <input type="checkbox" name="info"/>.info


  <input class="text" type="submit" name="submitBtn" value="Sök domännamn"/>

  </form>

  <?php
  if (isset($_POST['submitBtn'])){
  $domainbase = (isset($_POST['domainname'])) ? $_POST['domainname'] : '';
  $d_all = (isset($_POST['all'])) ? 'all' : '';
  $d_se = (isset($_POST['se'])) ? 'se' : '';
  $d_nu = (isset($_POST['nu'])) ? 'nu' : '';
  $d_eu = (isset($_POST['eu'])) ? 'eu' : '';
  $d_biz = (isset($_POST['biz'])) ? 'biz' : '';
  $d_com = (isset($_POST['com'])) ? 'com' : '';
  $d_net = (isset($_POST['net'])) ? 'net' : '';
  $d_org = (isset($_POST['org'])) ? 'org' : '';
  $d_info = (isset($_POST['info'])) ? 'info' : '';

  // Check domains only if the base name is big enough
  if (strlen($domainbase)>2){
  ?>
  <h1>Results</h1>
  <div id="result">
  <?php
  if (($d_se != '') || ($d_all != '') ) showDomainResult($domainbase.".se",'whois.iis.se','not found');
  if (($d_nu != '') || ($d_all != '') ) showDomainResult($domainbase.".nu",'whois.nic.nu', 'NO MATCH for');
  if (($d_eu != '') || ($d_all != '') ) showDomainResult($domainbase.".eu",'whois.eu','AVAILABLE');
  if (($d_biz != '') || ($d_all != '') ) showDomainResult($domainbase.".biz",'whois.nic.biz','Not found');
  if (($d_com != '') || ($d_all != '') ) showDomainResult($domainbase.".com",'whois.crsnic.net','No match for');
  if (($d_net != '') || ($d_all != '') ) showDomainResult($domainbase.".net",'whois.crsnic.net','No match for');
  if (($d_org != '') || ($d_all != '') ) showDomainResult($domainbase.".org",'whois.publicinterestregistry.net','NOT FOUND');
  if (($d_info != '') || ($d_all != '') ) showDomainResult($domainbase.".info",'whois.afilias.net','NOT FOUND');
  ?>
  </div></div>
  <?php
  }
  }
  ?>
  </body>
```

Comment: yeah just loop it, you could also use some sort of ob_flush so results are sent to browser as they come in, note use $con = @fsockopen($server, 43,$errno, $errstr, 2); as default time is too long and will time out on whois.iis.se as its offline

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to split the lines in the textarea into an array using explode with a newline delimiter, then do your WHOIS lookups in a foreach loop.

```
$manydomains = explode("\n", $domainbase);
foreach ($manydomains as $domain){
<your code here>
}
```

Comment: Thanks Canuteson! Your code works, but it returns a space on the domains. For example:
"test1 .com"
"test2 .com"
"test3.com"

How can I get rid of the space?

Comment: Solved it by turning the new lines into a comma before using explode...
$newlines = str_replace("\n",",",$domainbase);
$manydomains = explode(",", $newlines);
foreach ($manydomains as $domain){<your code here>
}
TANKS!